# Don't understand how to show the caption when hovering image

Tags: html, css

I'm having some difficulty with this example:

```
<img src="image1/<?php echo $file; ?>.jpg" style="width:500px" /> 
<p id="caption"><?php echo $caption; ?></p>
```

I'm trying to get the caption with CSS when hovering the image.

I tried to use `a img{hover;}` and `p {hover;}`.

Is there a way for me to get the caption when hovering the image? The example is in PHP and if it was in CSS or Javascript maybe I could search for it, but so far I can't find a solution for this.

I appreciate any explanation & examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/* by default, hide caption: */
#caption { display: none; } 
/* if caption is next to a hovered img, show: */
img:hover + #caption { display: block; }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pttsm/)

- `+` is the [Adjacent Sibling Selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector), supported from IE8.
- [`:hover`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/hover.html) pseudoclass is used to style elements the mouse goes over
- Note that if you want to use more than one caption in your document, you should use a class instead of an id. Ids must be unique in the document.

If you need something that works in IE7, consider HTML like this:

```
<div class="image-with-caption">
    <img src="whatever.png" style="width:200px" /> 
    <p class="caption">caption</p> 
</div>
```

And the CSS would be:

```
.caption { display: none; }
.image-with-caption:hover .caption { display: block; }​
```

​[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pttsm/1/)

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `+`

Comment: Hi Baz, Thanks for the reply! Wow thanks for the examples and explanations. It makes a lot of sense. I appreciate you writing this. I will test it out. I'll get to you.

Comment: Hi Baz, I apologizes for replying back. Thanks for the examples and the explanation. I definitely learn a lot about IE, I actually see the differences. I really appreciated that you wrote that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want `img:hover {/* css */}`

Actually, you probably want to do something like this:

```
<div class="hoverme">
  <img src="image1/<?php echo $file; ?>.jpg" style="width:500px" /> 
  <span><?php echo $caption; ?></span> 
</div>
```

and then in your CSS:

```
div.hoverme span{
    display: none;
}

div.hoverme:hover span{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: To ensure it is displayed over the other elements.  Sorry, it's a copy-paste out of one of my projects so the opacity is probably not necessary.

Comment: `z-index` has absolutely no effect on `position: static` elements, which is default. Only works on positioned elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Adding_z-index

Comment: Yeah, that's because I removed the extra CSS that included `position:absolute` -- like I said, copy-paste error.  I'll edit it out if it bugs you that much!

Comment: Hi Ametren Thanks for the reply! I will look over it.

Comment: @ametren It's not about me and my personal preferences. This is a site for professional programmers, so act like one. `z-index` has already enough myths around it.

Answer (score 2):

To affect the style of the `p` while hovering over the `img`:

```
img:hover + #caption {
    display: block; /* or whatever...*/
}
```

Or:

```
img:hover ~ #caption {
    display: block; /* or whatever... */
}
```

It's worth noting that these examples assume that you have only *one* `p` element with an `id` of 'caption,' if you have *multiple* `p` elements with that `id`, then you need to use a `class` instead, as an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document.

The `+` is the CSS adjacent-sibling combinator, and selects the `#caption` that immediately follows the `img` over which the user is hovering.

The `~` is the CSS general-sibling combinator, and selects any sibling `#caption` element that is a later-sibling of the `img` which is hovered; regardless of any elements that might appear in between (though they do have to be siblings within the same parent element).

Reference:

- [CSS selectors, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching).

Comment: Thank you kindly! ...though I realise that I cover mostly the same ground as your own. Of course yours is similarly wonderful! *cough* =D

Comment: "Well, let’s not start sucking each other’s dicks quite yet." :)

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the reply!. Your example looks similar to baz and you also cover ground on the rules. Thanks for the examples and explanations. It also makes a lot of sense. I appreciate you writing this. I will test it out too. I'll get to you. Thanks

Comment: Good use of the sibling combinator, this solves the problem that my answer also tries to solve, but in a much more concise way.

Comment: Hi David, I apologizes for replying back. I want to also thanks for the examples and the explanation! I definitely learn a lot about some rules. I really appreciated that you took time to do research and it write. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript events onMouseOver and onMouseOut to show/hide the caption, something like this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="width:500px"
    onMouseOver="document.getElementById('caption').style.display='block'"
    onMouseOut="document.getElementById('caption').style.display='none'" />
<p id="caption" style="display:none">Caption here</p>
```

Comment: -1 Javascript is completely unjustified here and just messes up the HTML source.