# My CSS code is not reading in TinyMCE correctly

Tags: php, html, css, image, tinymce

A few month back I posted a question about how to show the caption when hovering over an image.

This is the thread:

[Don't understand how to show the caption when hovering image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057056/dont-understand-how-to-show-the-caption-when-hovering-image)

The issue is that when I used TinyMce to edit the caption, it won't show the caption hovering. Instead it doesn't show any caption, it just hovers.

This is editor side (I shortened it):

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
  tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "textareas",
        elements : "ajaxfilemanager",
        theme : "advanced",
});
//]]</script>
```

This is output:

```
<html> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<style>
#caption { display: none;font:12px Times New Roman;}
img:hover + #caption { position: absolute; display: block;}
.caption { display:none; text-decoration: none; font:12px Times New Roman;}
.image-with-caption:hover .caption {display: block; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover { text-decoration: none; } 
</style>

<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo(stripslashes($_POST['content'])); ?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the input I copy and paste the code into TinyMCE:

```
 <table width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td>
 <div class="image-with-caption">
 <a href="images/artistc.php">
 <img src="images/imagec08.jpg" style="width:209px" />
 <p id="caption">Caption 3</p>
 </a>  
 </div>
 </td>
 <td>
 <div class="image-with-caption">
 <a href="images/artistb.php">
 <img src="images/imageb12.jpg" style="width:195px" />
 <p id="caption">Caption 5</p> 
 </a>
 </div>
 </td>
 <td>
 <div class="image-with-caption">
 <a href="images/artista.php">
 <img src="images/imagea02.jpg" style="width:260px" />
 <p id="caption">Caption 4</p>
 </a> 
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Any suggestions and advice would be appreciated. I just want to know why it doesn't show the caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question, but I see you have several tags with same id. That is not allowed. Maybe if you fix that, it helps to fix the issue. You should replace the `id="caption"` by `class="caption"` (or anything else), and then, modify your css replacing `#caption` by `.caption`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will make some adjustments base on your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I make some adjustments and it works! Can you tell me why TinyMce can't read 'id'? TinyMce read the 'class' instead of 'id' but the css code is working differently than the original one. Is it because of the change from 'id' to 'class' that why it change a little. The change is that the caption is hovering away from the image meaning if my cursor is not near the image it still show the caption. Before than I just hover the image and the caption appears. Any suggestions? This question is almost solve. I was afraid that no one can answer this question! I really appreciate that you help me.

Comment: @LightM1, I do not understand you completely, can you post your new code on jsfiddle.net so i can help you??

Comment: I don't think I could put the tinymce in the jsfiddle.net. I think it has to do with the replace 'id' to 'class'

Comment: Can you post your new code here at least?? I'm blind now. I just can guess you forgot to replace some "#caption" by ".caption"

Comment: Here is the code: #caption { display: none; text-decoration: none; font:12px Times New Roman;}
img:hover + #caption { position: absolute; display: block; text-decoration: none;}

.caption { display:none; text-decoration: none; font:12px Times New Roman;}
.image-with-caption:hover .caption {position: absolute; display: block; text-decoration: none;}

Comment: It's the same code. I don't know how you figure it out that I have to change the id to class in order to work. It work but css code is acting strangely now

Comment: Does it has to do with tinymce if so then I'll find another way

Comment: So, you changed all the `id="caption"` by `class="caption"` in html. Then you changed all the `#caption` by `.caption` in css.

Comment: I'm not sure tinyMCE is the problem. I guess adding a '+' in css may help. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/92p39/) and make sure your html and css are exactly the same.

Comment: No, the '+' make the caption not appear.

Comment: I just want to say 'Thanks' for helping me to resolve this issue. I guess I'll live the way it is ...  meaning the caption hover, it's not as bad I thought it will be but it looks fine. As long I can edit the caption then it's fine. Thanks